# What do you call this class of matrices with a unique positive eigenvalue associated to a graph?

Tags: matrices, sp.spectral-theory, terminology, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I am looking for the name of a class of *symmetric* matrices $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ that I can associate to a (finite simple) graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{1,...,n\}$ and that have the following properties:

1. $M_{ij}>0$ if $ij\in E$.
2. $M_{ij}=0$ if $i\not=j$ and $ij\not\in E$.
3. $M$ has a unique positive eigenvalue of multiplicity one.

I do not make any assumptions about the entries on the diagonal. If the name fits $-M$ (having inverted signs and inequalities in 1. and 3.) that is fine as well.

---

**Some notes**

These are not quite (negated) [*Colin de Verdiére matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_de_Verdi%C3%A8re_graph_invariant) since the strong Arnold property is missing. But I was thinking that perhaps some other kind of discretized differential operator (Schrödinger operator?) will match.

If these matrices have no established name, then the next most relevant thing for me would be a name for the following class of symmetric matrices, this time independent of any graph:

1. $M_{ij}\ge 0$ for all $i\not=j$.
2. $M$ has a unique positive eigenvalue of multiplicity one.

Without 2. these are called [*$Z$-matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)) or [*Metzler matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix), depending on the sign.